# Is there a way after Sysprep the appx file I installed was still there and successfully works?

Tags: windows-10, sysprep, installation-package

I installed appx file for current and provisioned for new user, they are successfully installed and works, but when after I Sysprep the application was not installed for new user, then going back to the account where I install the application it doesn't work anymore. Is there a way after Sysprep the appx file I installed was still there and successfully works?.

Comment: If the application was not installed it means you didn't update the install.wim file

Comment: So I need to use  Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK) in order to create a .wim file?

Comment: If you want to create a custom .wim you do. You could just apply the image using DISM but creating a .wim is another method

Comment: Mean that if I will apply the image using DISM, I will create first a .wim?.regarding in this code 'Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:c:\images\myimage.wim /Index:1 /mountdir:c:\test\offline' it uses .wim I'm not familiar with .wim file. Thanks

Comment: Windows installation uses .wim files, do some research, on how to apply system images